# Why doesn't my local notification gets sent when I receive a remote notification?

Tags: swift, push-notification, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging, localnotification

I am trying to send a location notification when I receive a remote FCM notification because as far as I know FCM notification doesn't support action buttons. But the local notification get sent only sometimes and it seems to me that it is random. I always get the remote notification though. I'd like to get the local notification in all three states, foreground, background, or when app is killed.

Here's where I add the buttons in didFinishLoadingWithOptions:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {


  let incrementAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    incrementAction.identifier = "First"
    incrementAction.title = "First"
    incrementAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.foreground
    incrementAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true
    incrementAction.isDestructive = true


    let decrementAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    decrementAction.identifier = "second"
    decrementAction.title = "second"
    decrementAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.foreground
    decrementAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true
    decrementAction.isDestructive = false

    // Category
    let counterCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    counterCategory.identifier = "BOOKING_CATEGORY"

    // A. Set actions for the default context
    counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction, decrementAction],
                               for: UIUserNotificationActionContext.default)

    // B. Set actions for the minimal context //No more than 2
    counterCategory.setActions([incrementAction, decrementAction],
                               for: UIUserNotificationActionContext.minimal)

    // iOS 9 support
else if #available(iOS 9, *) {

    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: NSSet(object: counterCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

}
```

Here's where I create the local notification :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {
        // Do something you want when the app is active
    } else {
        // Do something else when your app is in the background
    }

    // fire a local notification upon receiving FCM notification
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification() 
    localNotification.alertTitle = "Notification Title"
    localNotification.alertBody = "more details"
    localNotification.alertAction = "ShowDetails"
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(5) as Date
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotification.category = "BOOKING_CATEGORY"
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

    print("Push notification received bkg: \(userInfo)")
    print("completed"  , completionHandler)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your payload for the notification look like? Do you have a notification payload, data payload or both?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have both, I implemented the function that receives local notification in app delegate class and it seems it gets called every time. So my problem is how to schedule a local notification when the app is killed or in background and I receive a remote notification, since when app is killed the app delegate functions won't be called!

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that your app always handles how a notification is displayed (even when its not running or is in the background) you need to set a `data` payload **only** e.g.

```
{
  "to":"push_token",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
      "title": "New Message",
      "message": "Bob sent you a message",
    }
}
```

Setting a `notification` payload triggers FCM to automatically display the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. If you use a data payload instead you have full control over how to display the notification.

For more info check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: The reason I'd like to use local notification is that FCM doesn't support action buttons on their notification yet and they recommend to use local notification for it.

Comment: I also build my own local notification each time `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is fired, but the only way I could get it to fire every time, when the app is not running, in background/foreground was to pass a data payload only. Adding `notification` tells FCM to handle the notification. Have you tried a data only payload?

Comment: Hmm ... good point, I'll try , although, I gave up on this for now as it is not really a crucial feature but I'll give this another shot , thanks for the comment

Comment: It took me a while to get it working properly. It wasn't 100% clear from their docs, but it is possible to make your own local notification for each of the 3 main app states

Comment: alright, I'll give it a try when I find some time, will get back to this later ... cheers!